# What is the best way to store heterogeneus data in tables with static schema

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a set of characters

`s1,s2,s3,...,sn`

Such as (|| indicates [cardinality of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality))

`|s1|!=|s2|!=|s3|!=...|sn|`

Each set is associated to a user.

I need to store such things in a relational database in some way.

There are two ways that I dug up from my memory:

1. Adding a redundancy to the table that stores the character in such way that

   | UserID | Character |
   | --- | --- |
   | <id> | char |

   With userID being a foreign key pointing at the user table, hence adding a redundancy
2. Using a JSON file on the server (a random HTTP server) and putting the URL of the file in the database (which would eliminate the redundancy, but the file has to go through a JSON parser and the whole thing needs to be manipulated still)

Which way should I go considering that `max(|si|)=81`?

I am trying to represent a matrix of characters on a webpage that can be customized (hence the separation of characters) by picking number of rows,cols and by picking the characters

The matrix is like

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| char 1 | char2 |
| char 3 | char 4 |
| char 5 | char 6 |
| char 7 | char 8 |

(this is just an example but it extends horizontally and vertically

Comment: Your notation for "a succession of characters" (i.e. a string?) does not mesh with my mental model of set cardinality (a sequence or succession is not a set). Please provide better sample data.

Comment: So every user in your database has a single string value associated with them, and the maximum length of each string is 81 characters? And you're thinking of storing this in a MySQL database using a new row, each containing 1 single character character in a `char(1)` column with an FK to the users table?

Comment: It would help if you would explain what the string actually represents - I think you might be having an X/Y Problem.

Comment: Added context @Dai

Comment: What exactly is a "matrix of characters that can be customized"? I get the feeling you're using overly pedantic or theoretic terminology because you're keen to share your newfound knowledge, but it's not helping us with reading your post. There's nothing wrong with using "normal" or everyday language to describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: look at the edit @Dai

Comment: @Dai It is basically a table with letters in it that's it... you can customize the table size and the letters in it

Comment: And each cell in the matrix has only 1 character in it? Not strings?

Comment: @Dai yes single characters

Comment: I'd just store it in a `varchar(n)` (or `nvarchar(n)`) column in your `users` table.

Comment: wouldn't i lose the info related to the rows/columns structure? because modifying the string to contain separators for row/col seems clunky

Comment: Ask yourself if that structure adds any value - is there any advantage to being able to update individual characters like that? Personally I don't think there is because it adds considerable extra complexity to your database design and your queries but for what benefit?

Comment: so an extra table with the uid,string with separator,#rows,#cols is the best way to go?

Comment: If it's individual single characters, what do you need or want a "separator" for? Or why store information about rows and columns when you could represent that in different lines of text (`\r\n`) in the text blob column?

Comment: ok thx for the answer i'll mark this as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my issue @Dai's comments solved it

> If it's individual single characters, what do you need or want a "separator" for? Or why store information about rows and columns when you could represent that in different lines of text (\r\n) in the text blob column? – Dai